# Brownian motion, submartingale

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingales

I'm trying to prove whether a given process is a submartingale.

Let $W = \{W_t, t ≥ 0\}$ - m-dimensional Brownian motion.

Prove that $( ||W_t||, F_t )_{t ≥ 0}$ is a submartingale (with a.s. continuous trajectories), where $||\cdot||$ is the Euclidean norm in R^m.

Comment: Hint : $\|.\|$ is a convex function. Now use Jensen's inequality on the conditional expectation.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.